# realshadow.js in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to implement the Realshadow.js found here: https://github.com/Indamix/real-shadow into wordpress.

When I load the .js I get two errors:

TypeError: $ is undefined

> $.fn.realshadow = init;  in realshadow.js

For this kind of error the first solution I usually find is to use jQuery instead of $.

So I've changed the $.fn.realshadow  into jQuery.fn.realshadow

This fix the first error.

The second one is:

ReferenceError: realshadow is not defined

> realshadow.reset();   in demo.js

Now if I use the html file from the github .zip file, everything works. If I simply put the very exact HTML code into a wordpress page, it doesn't work. I think there must be something wrong with the way WP deal with external JS code.

Also realshadow.js should be working even without jQuery.

This is a brand new installation of wordpress, using an almost empty child theme of twenty fourteen theme.

Is there anyone that was able to implement realshadow.js into wordpress?

Comment: Did you set the right path to the JS file ? Is the realshadow.js file being loaded in the wp-footer.php file ?

Comment: Yes, the paths are correct, and they are loaded from footer.php in the exact order.

Comment: If I've helped you solve your problem, please approve my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Wordpress uses the full `jQuery` ( no-conflict mode ) not the the shorthand `$` .

Try `jQuery( '.element' ).realshadow();` or

```
(function($) {
// Do Stuff
})(jQuery)
```

and use `$` as a local variable.

#### EDIT

It works, you just need to get rid of the `demo.js` file because it's unnecessary. If you run `jQuery( '.entry-title').realshadow();` in the console it works.

Comment: Yep - it's common headache with 3-rd part .js libraries.

Comment: I'm afraid I did not understood well (sorry I'm and absolute beginner in JS)

Comment: Wordpress places `jQuery` in no-conflict mode - which means that any references to `$` will be undefined. So the easiest solution is to use `jQuery` instead of the dollar sign. You're second error `ReferenceError: realshadow is not defined` (most) likely means the library wasn't loaded correctly. It could be the order, or the actual path to the library isn't correct.

Comment: OK Thanks, the first issue seems fixed. But the second one is still there. Actually I'm pretty sure the file is loaded correctly and in the correct order (first realshadow.js then demo.js exactly as in the HTML file).

Comment: Best practice is to load external scripts in `functions.php` using `wp_register_script` and if you copied them from the demo verbatim, they're most likely wrong for a variety of reasons.

Comment: What's the path that you're using? Put the code is a jsFiddle, or post it somewhere.

Comment: have a look here: http://www.popsite.it/labs/vicario (the code is loaded in functions.php as you suggest and the HTML code is in the header.php, so it should appear immediately.

Comment: OK, I've found that if I do load jquery in the index.html (in the demo) I've got the same ReferenceError: realshadow is not defined

Comment: The problem is the `demo.js` file, don't use it. if you open up the console and run. `jQuery( '.entry-title').realshadow();` it works.